# Related products based on grouping tags limit memory. Use instead collection with certain handle tag

Tags: shopify

By starting from this point https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/related-products 
I end up to this custom and working code:

```
    {% comment %}
     Get dynamic tag from product and create static collection handle 
    {% endcomment %}
        {% for tag in product.tags %}
            {% if tag contains 'IDSeries_' %}
                {% assign ser_tag = tag %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="/collections/all/{{ ser_tag | handleize }}">
                            <h2>{{ ser_tag | remove: "IDSeries_" | prepend: "Go to products with Serie ID number:" }}</h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    {% comment %} 
     Return products by using the extracted tag 
    {% endcomment %}
        {% for product in collections.all.products %}
            {% if product.tags contains ser_tag %}
                {{ product.title }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

**This above does work. But it's not the solution!**
*because limited memory,* it works only for the first bunch of products and not for all.

- By considering I have **twenty five thousands products** all with an incremental *"IDSeries_'INT'"*
- ***My goal is:*** to show products with same specific "IDSeries_'INT'".
- Since when this already happens at collection tag url like this `<a href="/collections/all/{{ ser_tag | handleize }}">`
- I was wondering if I can `return` products (into a section products) that are already filtered at the collection handle tag url layer.

So at Themes/Debut/Sections/product-template.liquid
I am trying the following ***with no luck***:

```
{% assign collection_handle = ser_tag %}
    {% for product in collections.all[collection_handle].products %}
        {{ product.title }}
    {% endfor %}
```

***Question:***

Any clue on how to achieve a consistent result for such a big stock of products?

***Extra question:***

- For a store with 30k products each with five tags (so 150k tags in
  total).
- Does tags have any limitation?

> I also created a Shopify community topic https://community.shopify.com/c/Technical-Q-A/Related-products-based-on-grouping-tags-limit-memory-Use-instead/td-p/759705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions for your problem, that doesn't affect the speed of the site.

#### Search based + Javascript

The search page on Shopify can search for tags as well.

So if you make a fetch request to the search page like so:

```
fetch('/search?q=IDSeries_*').then(res => res).then(res => console.log(res))
```

This will return you the products that include this tag combination and you can append it with javascript.

So you will populate the products with javascript.

#### GraphQL

You can use the Storefront GraphQL API to make a request and get products by specific tag, like so:

```
{
    products(first: 10, query:"tag:>'IDSeries_'"){
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will require understanding of GraphQL and especially their Store-Front API (not the Admin API).

---

> For a store with 30k products each with five tags (so 150k tags in total).
>
> Does tags have any limitation?

The `all_tags` object for the collection can return up to 1000 tags, the rest will be skipped. They need to be unique tags, repeatable tags doesn't count.

Other than that there are no limitations to my knowledge.

Comment: Hi @drip great idea to use fetch javascript I ended up with this code ```fetch("/search?q=tag").then(res=>res.text()).then(data=>{$("#div_id").html(data)});``` but as you can see from any product page https://dev.na.it/ I display the entire search page. Any suggestion on how to display only the <li> results?

Comment: You can filter the html items with javascript or you can create a separate template called for example `search.ajax.liquid` with `{% layout none %}` at the top and list only the `li` elements there. So your fetch request must point to `/search?view=ajax&q=tag` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So at the end of the day to display tag search results in to a Shopify section I used `fetch()` and script looks like this:

```
<script>  
  {% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% if tag contains 'IDSeries_' %}
  {% assign ser_tag = tag %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  const url = '/search?view=serie_list&q={{ ser_tag }}';  
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text( 
  ))
  .then(data => {
    $('#serie_list_id').html(data);
});
</script>
```

Also as the magic @drip said I created a separate search template with `{% layout none %}` at the top and some other style